# In ElasticSearch, what is the equivalent for creating custom field types?

Tags: elasticsearch, search, indexing, solr

In Solr, my schema is very clean as I've defined 5 common field types used across 20 fields. The field type contains a base class (text, etc.), an index analyzer, and a query analyzer. In Elastic, is there no way to represent this other than to define my fields as a base type and then split up each field type into its two analyzers?

For example, for 20 common fields, I would still need to create two analyzers to represent my field type: customfield_index_analyzer and customfield_query_analyzer, and I would need to reference these two separate analyzers for every field in the Elastic mapping? I just want to make sure I'm doing this the right way, but it seems wrong and makes the configuration file less manageable and more prone to mistakes.

Comment: Note: I'm exploring using copy fields to see if this will help, but those seem to work differently in Elastic as well.

Comment: Can you show the current mapping you've come up with, and we'll see if we can improve it, pretty sure there's a way.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for https://discuss.elastic.co/t/custom-datatype-in-mappin/39634?